# Maven Plugin to mark empty directories

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

Is there something for Maven that I can use to create "placeholders" (e.g. a .empty or EMPTY) file for empty directories? Mercurial does not include empty directories so I need these directories filled hopefully via some automated way.

In the past, I used a Python script that does exactly this. I was hoping for a more Java-esque or Maven-esque approach.

Thanks

Comment: No never heard about that kind of plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use maven-antrun-plugin or gmaven-plugin to script putting a file in your directories. And then submit those empty files to your source control.

HOWEVER, this would have maven generate source code that is going to be checked in. Which is a bad idea (or at least not what you want to regular build to do).

If your source control does not keep track of empty directories, but they're needed for your build, I would recommend instead having a generate-source hook in your maven lifeycle that creates those. (Ideally, in your target directory to keep it clean, however since your source control won't keep track of them there is little harm in putting them right in your source folders if that makes your life easier).

Something like (consider that pseudo-code, absolutely not tested):

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugins>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</...>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>generate-source</phase>
          <goals><goal>antrun</...
          <configuration>
            <tasks>
              <mkdir dir="my directory1"/>
              <mkdir dir="my directory2"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I think it should fit well.

Would it be considered "right" to do this during the as a hook to 'clean'? From what I understand generate-source will be called before doing a compile.

Comment: Clean is a separate lifecycle from the standard compile/install. So I would say now (i.e. someone doing a rm -rf target; mvn install would not get the empty directories generated, which would be wrong). And yes, generate-sources is pretty early in the lifecycle (if you need even earlier, hook it to validate).